# How to insert (int) and (date) type?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sql-insert

I'd like to insert ID(int), title(varchar), plot(varchar), release_date(date), target(varchar) into exsiting database.

Here is the code which showed no data at all.

How can I add a date type value into a connected database?

```
else if (e.getSource() == this.insert2) {

    String n = this.IDField.getInt();
    String m = this.titleField.getText();
    String f = this.plotField.getText();
    String p = this.release_dateField.getText();
    String t = this.targetField.getText();

    String[] name = {"MOVIE_ID","title","plot","release_date","main_target"};
    this.dt = new DefaultTableModel(name, 0);
    /**try~catch*/
    try{
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into DB2020_MOVIEINFO values('" + n + "', '" + m + "', '" + f + "', '" + p + "', '" + t + "')");

        ResultSet rset_mv = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DB2020_MOVIEINFO");
        while (rset_mv.next()) {
            Object[] data = {rset_mv.getString(1), rset_mv.getString(2), rset_mv.getString(3), rset_mv.getString(4), rset_mv.getString(5)};
            dt.addRow(data);
        }

    } 
    catch(SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.jt = new JTable(dt);
    jt.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.decode("#b76e79"));
    jt.setSelectionBackground(Color.decode("#f7f6f0"));
    this.jsp = new JScrollPane(jt);
    jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    this.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.centerPanel.removeAll();
    this.centerPanel.updateUI();
    this.centerPanel.add(jsp);
    this.centerPanel.setVisible(true);
}
```

new code I applied after Mureinik's advise. (I extracted date-part)

```
 else if (e.getSource() == this.insert2) {


            Int id = this.IDField.getInt();
            String title = this.titleField.getText();
            String plot = this.plotField.getText();
            String target = this.targetField.getText();

            String[] name = {"MOVIE_ID","title","plot","main_target"};
            this.dt = new DefaultTableModel(name, 0);
            /**try~catch*/
            try (PreparedStatement ps = 
                     conn.prepareStatement("insert into DB2020_MOVIEINFO values(?, ?, ?, ?)") {
                    ps.setInt(1, id); // id should be an int
                    ps.setString(2, title);
                    ps.setString(3, plot);
                    ps.setString(4, target);
                }
            catch(SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }


            this.jt = new JTable(dt);
            jt.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.decode("#b76e79"));
            jt.setSelectionBackground(Color.decode("#f7f6f0"));
            this.jsp = new JScrollPane(jt);
            jt.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(800,600));
            this.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            this.centerPanel.removeAll();
            this.centerPanel.updateUI();
            this.centerPanel.add(jsp);
            this.centerPanel.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Comment: Please, please, *please* use the [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) class instead.  You can create one from a `Connection`'s [`.prepareStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to force these datatypes to strings, you could use a `PreparedStatement` and let the JDBC driver do the heavy lifting for you. As a side effect, this will also help protect you application from SQL Injection attacks:

```java
try (PreparedStatement ps = 
     conn.prepareStatement("insert into DB2020_MOVIEINFO values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) {
    ps.setInt(1, id); // id should be an int
    ps.setString(2, title);
    ps.setString(3, plot);
    ps.setDate(4, releaseDate); // releaseDate should be java.sql.Date
    ps.setString(5, target);
}
```

Comment: Side note: Since Java 8, you can use `java.sql.Date`'s `.valueOf` static method to convert from `java.time.LocalDate`

Comment: @Powerlord Better yet, a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver will accept a LocalDate directly (assuming the column is a `DATE [WITHOUT TIME ZONE]` or string type), using `setObject`.

Comment: @Mureinik, Thank you so so so much! but sadly, it didn't work weirdly. I got an error message saying <Int cannot be resolved to a type> and <Syntax error, insert")" to complete ResourceSpecification> and <the method getInt() is undefined for the type JTextField>. It's my very first time to try JDBC and never learned java before. so my apologies for my awful code beforehand. (I edited the main text)

Comment: @hollyjolly `Int` is not the same as `int`. Java is a case-sensitive language. The second error is due to the fact that `JTextField` doesn't have a method `getInt()`. Neither problem has anything to do with JDBC, but are 1) fundamental Java knowledge and 2) knowing the API of the classes you are using (Java comes with [extensive documentation of its API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/)!)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for very kind and clear point! was my first time using java, so I had no idea that java doesn't provide getInt function! Again, Thank you:)